# How to combine xlsx files in python anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, data-analysis, join

I'm learning to do data analysis, but the DB they have given me its fractionated in 13 sections with 13 files each section. I have inspected each section and found that the first 10 columns repeat on each file as headers to join the files, especially two columns 'id' and 'date'. As context this DB is 2 million records of fake medical records, so I want to join all the rows that have the same id and date with all the other columns, BUT I want to keep rows that don't have any other matching row.

```
files = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
df_list = []
for the file in files:
  df = pd.read_excel(file)
  df['file'] = file
  df_list.append(df)
```

So far I have been able to join all the files, but I couldn't make the join with column validation. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat the dataframes

```
fdf = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: sorry, I tried your way but it didn't work apparently there was some problem with my indexing but I solve it. Thanks